# C++ . Block console input after 5 characters

Tags: c++, c++11, input, inputstream, user-input

firstly thanks for all.

My question

I want to force console not allow me even type ,after a cin,when I have typed 5 characters.

I need something like "checking while you type"... I don't know ...
I need a string only 5 chars length PLUS not allow me type more than 5 chars while imputing

Thanks

Comment: can u show us your code

Comment: @RohanGala I got no code at all hah.

Answer (score 0):

On UNIXes you'd put the standard input stream into non-canonical mode (using the flag `ICANON` if I recall correctly) with `tcgetattr()` and `tcsetattr()`. Once that's done you need to deal with each character hit and display characters as appropriate.

On other systems you'll probably use orher approaches (e.g., `kbhit()` if I recall correctly).

Comment: Any code as example?

Comment: @DimitrisKatikaridis: sure: there are plenty (including some I posted in the distant past, including [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20023604/1120273)). Just search the Internet for the keywords provided! It seems now it is time for you to do work.

Comment: Thanks for this.will work in it and I will comment